# java buf[--pos] = (byte)b Please, explain me what is in the square brackets

Tags: java

I'm reading sourcecode of PushbackInputStream to gain my understand about unread() method: http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/java/io/PushbackInputStream.java.html but on the line 194: buf[--pos] = (byte)b makes me don't understand what that said.
Can anyone tell me the meaning of --pos in that line?
Thanks in advance.

Ps: I even try to code this:

```
class Test2 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] c = { 'd', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e',
            'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd' };
    char temp = 'o';
    c[--1] = tmp;
 }
}
```

but eclipse tells me: invalid argument operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--` is decrement operator, it makes sense only for a field (variable) not constant.

`buf[--pos] = (byte)b;` means set byte value `b` to `buf[pos - 1]` and `pos` would result in being decremented.

Answer (score 1):

`--pos` means "decrease the value of `pos` by one, and use the resulting value".

This cannot be applied to a constant: `--1` is not valid. However, you could just write `0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`1` is a constant. You cannot decrement a constant - or change its value -

However you can do this: `pos = 1;`, `buf[--pos]` will do what you want it to do, because `pos` is a variable, and not a constant.

alternatively just use `buf[0]`

Answer (score 0):

In the real code, pos is the current index into the buffer. To unread a byte, you need to decrement that index by one and store the specified byte at the new current index location in the buffer.

--pos has as side effect decrementing pos by one, and as result the new value of pos, so `buf[--pos] = (byte)b;` does the job.

Because of the side effect, the operand of `--` has to be something that can be decremented by one. A constant cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid argument operation error is because you are doing the decrement operation on a number instead of a variable.